# Virtualbox VBoxGuestAdditions stuck at 100% on Windows 11 & 10 VM

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-11

#### Virtualbox VBoxGuestAdditions stuck at 100% on Windows 11 & 10 VM

#### Problem

I am trying to resize the screen on a ***Windows 11 VM*** on Virtualbox and I am having trouble with adding the ***VBoxGuestAdditions*** to do so.

When I go into, ***Devices*** and click ***Insert Guest Additions CD Image***, I get a prompt saying:

> Could not find the VirtualBox Guest Additions disk image file.
>
> Do you wish to download this disk image file from the Internet?
>
> Cancel & Download Buttons

I click Download and it starts to download but it never finishes and stays stuck at 100%.

On the right side of the VM I get this pop-up:

> Downloading Guest Additions ...
>
> Name: VBoxGuestAdditions
>
> During certificate downloading:
>
> Unknown reason
>
> 100% BAR

#### I'll list the things I have tried so far.

1. When I first tried to install the *VBoxGuestAdditions* on the *Windows 11 VM* it got stuck at 100% and then the VM froze and then my host system also froze.

   - I had to force shutdown my laptop.
2. I thought an update was the issue, so, then I updated the *Windows 11 VM* and then restarted the VM **2 times** to make sure any weirdness was sorted out.

   - This didn't help; although, I didn't get a whole system freeze, the installation was still stuck at 100%.
3. I searched the issue and found the problem is already known by the *Virtualbox team* as of this post --> [Guest additions freezes win 11](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=108519)

   - A site moderator says to create a ticket in the [Bugtracker](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker) but as of writing this it returns a "502 Bad Gateway" error, so I am not able to create a ticket.
4. After this, I tried to install it on ***another Windows 11 VM*** and it had the same issue.
5. I wasn't sure if this was only an issue with the *Windows 11 installation* so I tried *Windows 10*.

   - To my surprise (Not really a surprise... sadly) it had the same problem.

Now you may be asking why have I not seen this issue before.

- Well I usually work without an external monitor with the Windows VM's on my laptop since it is 16" and also, I don't really use Windows that often unless it is to play games or test something and that rarely requires me to use an external monitor. If I do, I did't think to resize the screen until now.

#### Now to why I am here.

- Has anyone had this same or similar issue and has solved the problem?

I am running Virtualbox on Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS. I don't have the issue with Linux any of the Linux OS's I have VM's of so I don't know what to do next. I know I am not the only person with this issue, so, someone has to have come across it at some point.

My system looks like this:

```
- Hardware : Alienware m16 R1
- Memory   : 16 GB
- Processor: 13th Gen Intel Core i7
- Graphics : NVIDIA / Mesa Intel UHD
- OS       : Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
- DE       : Gnome 42.9
- Window   : X11
```

Virtualbox :

```
- Version  : 7.0.10_Ubuntu r158379
```

Comment: I am not certain. Perhaps uninstall Virtual Box, restart, install the newest version of Virtual Box and try installing the Additions in the Guest machine again